# Function not iterating and displaying list properly

Tags: c#

Expected Result: The user inputs certain symptoms, the program will turn them from false to true, if for example, both headache and vomiting = true, then flu = true etc.

Actual Result: The symptoms aren't displaying true or false correctly in the command line.

---

Code:

I've initialized it as a bool list and created the list below:

```
Dictionary<string, bool> FACTS = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
```

Here's what my addFACTS() function looks like:

```
void addFACTS()
    {
        FACTS.Add("headache", false);
        FACTS.Add("vomiting", false);
    }
```

Here's what my countFACTS() function looks like:

```
private int countFACTS()
    {
        int count = 0;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string,bool> fact in FACTS)
        {
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
```

Below is the function that's causing the list to display incorrectly:

```
private void infer()
    {
        do
        {
            numberOfFacts = countFACTS();
            (FACTS["headache"] && FACTS["vomiting"]) ? FACTS["flu"] = true : FACTS["flu"] = false;
        }
        while (numberOfFacts != countFACTS());
    }
```

Comment: Well, in `AddFacts` you fill the list by `false` values and can access them only by index or using `Linq`, Accessing by name, like `headache` isn't possible

Comment: There is a lot wrong here so would be good to read up on how to use lists and dictionaries. Since `Facts` is just a list of bools you have no link between symptom and bool. You probably want to use a `Dictionary<string, bool>`. Also, you can't just do `FACTS.` to access a list. Once converted to a Dictionary you can do `FACTS["headache"]`

Comment: @Matt sorry but could you give me a code example, I tried dictionaries before hand with ```Dictionary<int,bool> FACTS = new Dictionary<int, bool>();``` and I wasn't able to figure out how to use it

Comment: I've added an answer, could you explain what you're trying to do with the loop in the infer function? What is `countFACTS ` etc? Can update answer with more help :)

Comment: @Matt I've updated the code with the countFACTS functoin

Comment: Aside: [Dictionary<TKey,TValue>.Count Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.count?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: Updated answer, i think the compilation issue is your ternary operators!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you want to convert your list to a Dictionary.

`Dictionary<string, bool> FACTS = new Dictionary<string, bool>();`

To add to a Dictionary you need to provide a unique key and a value. The key in your case will be a symptom e.g. headache and the value is true or false.

`FACTS.Add("headache", true);`

Once you've filled the list to access it you can do `FACTS["headache"]` however note a few things.

Dictionaries are case sensitive when indexing into them

If the key is missing, using the `[""]` (indexing) syntax will throw an error (look into using TryGetValue or Linq for better accessing).

**After your update to dictionary**

You can simply do `FACTS.Count` to get the number of records in the dictionary so you can remove the countFACTS function.

Your code does nothing to modify the dictionary so your do/while loop will never loop a second time. Not sure what the intention is here?

When using the short-hand if statement (ternary operator)  it needs to be on the right-hand-side of the `=` so it should be

`FACTS["flu"] = FACTS["headache"] && FACTS["vomiting"] ? true : false;`

And this can be further simplified since the result of true is true you can just do

`FACTS["flu"] = FACTS["headache"] && FACTS["vomiting"];`

Answer (score 0):

You can not have key value pair using list You should use Dictionay insread List.

```
Dictionary<string,bool> FACTS = new Dictionary<string,bool>();
void addFACTS()
        {
            FACTS.Add("headache" , false);
            FACTS.Add("vomiting" , false);
            FACTS.Add("cramp", false);
            FACTS.Add("rash" , false);
            FACTS.Add("cough" , false);
            FACTS.Add("fatigue" , false);
            FACTS.Add("nausea" , false);
            FACTS.Add("dizziness" , false);
            FACTS.Add("cold" , false);
            FACTS.Add("chestPain" , false);
            FACTS.Add("infection" , false);
            FACTS.Add("flu" , false);
            FACTS.Add("healthy" , false);
            FACTS.Add("prescribeAntibiotics" , false);
            FACTS.Add("prescribePainkillers" , false);
            FACTS.Add("gastroenteritis" , false);
        }

private void infer()
{
     do
     {
        numberOfFacts = countFACTS();
        (FACTS["headache"] && FACTS["vomiting"]) ? FACTS["flu"] = true : FACTS["flu"] = 
     .... } 
     while (numberOfFacts != countFACTS());
}
```

Comment: I've updated my post with the new code, what am I doing wrong, I seem to still be getting red underlines under every line in the infer function